# How to create an object attribute without writing to database -- peewee -- python

Tags: peewee

Maybe i have an understanding problem. I try to make 2 tabeles in one database. But additionaly i need to have some temporary values in one class that i doen´t want to write to the database.
I try to switch to peewee and read the dokumentation but i find no solution at my own.
without peewee i would make an **init** method where i write my attributes. But where did i have to write them now?

```
from peewee import *
import datetime

db = SqliteDatabase('test.db', pragmas={'foreign_keys': 1})

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Sensor(BaseModel):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sort = IntegerField()
    name = TextField()
    #def __init__(self):
        #self.sometemporaryvariable = "blabla"

    def meineparameter(self, hui):
        self.hui = hui
        print(self.hui)

class Sensor_measure(BaseModel):
    id = ForeignKeyField(Sensor, backref="sensorvalues")
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    value = FloatField()

    class Meta:
        primary_key = CompositeKey("id", "timestamp")


db.connect()

db.create_tables([Sensor_measure, Sensor])

sensor1 = Sensor.create(id=2, sort=20, name="Sensor2")

#sensor1.sometemporaryvariable = "not so important to write to the database"

sensor1.save()
```

Comment: You can override `__init__`, just be sure to accept `**kwargs` and delegate to the parent init method.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to call `super()` whenever overriding a method in a subclass:

```py
class Sensor(BaseModel):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sort = IntegerField()
    name = TextField()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.sometemporaryvariable = "blabla"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```